# Xpath query to select JCR nodes of multiple primary types

Tags: xpath, jcr, jackrabbit, hippocms

I am trying to create an xpath query to select JCR nodes of multiple primary types.

For example, I could write a query like this:

```
/jcr:root/content//element(*, nt:unstructured)
```

to select all the nodes of type nt:unstructured, or this:

```
/jcr:root/content//element(*, nt:file)
```

to get all the nodes of type nt:file

Is it possible to write one query to select all the nodes of type nt:unstructured and of type nt:file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a where clause in which you filter on jcr:primaryType

/jcr:root/content//*[@jcr:primaryType='nt:file' or @jcr:primaryType='nt:unstructured']

Keep in mind that the queries you provided as an example also select on multiple types (namely super and child types.

Let's say you have a node of type project:article and a project:newsarticle in which newsarticle is extending the article node type.

When querying with

/jcr:root/content//element(*, project:article)

You will also find the nodes of both types.